# pip3 Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Win10, x64, Anaconda Python 3.7

I have recently 'upgraded' to Python 3.7 so some of my modules are missing, for example I am trying to use [pyfile](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile) by using `import plyfile` but I get following error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyfile'
```

Ok simple fix I'll `pip install plyfile`

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install plyfile
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: plyfile in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from plyfile) (1.16.3)
```

Ahh OK its not installed for py3.7 I'll `pip3 install plyfile`

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip3 install plyfile
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

errrr ok `pip3 --version`

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip3 --version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

So I had a look around SO for previous posts & there are a few & honestly after reading them I dont get what's going on.

So whats going on? Am I right to use `pip3` & its just badly installed or is there something deeper about the differences between the `pips` I'm not getting?

**Edit 1:** `pip install --upgrade pip` makes no difference

**Edit 2:**

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python --version
Python 3.7.3
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)
```

**Edit 3:**

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python -m pip install -U pip
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: Compare `python --version` and `pip --version`.

Comment: @phd see edit 2

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Downloaded [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Then from the terminal `python get-pip.py --ignore-installed`

Successful installation & upgrade,

```
(base) PS D:\Downloads> pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from d:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

`pip install plyfile` collected & installed `plyfile` & now `import plyfile` works

Solution from pip's git page issue #1892 [How do you remove pip from a pc if you installed by "get-pip.py"](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1892)